# Qtvector content modification not happening

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `struct functionStruct` and a `QVector<functionStruct>` . I am doing following..
when I click on a button the slot calls this function.

when I click 1st time it prints "somedoc" (expected)
but when I click 2nd time (and onwards) it prints nothing ( member is null)

```
int s = 0;

void foo()
{
    if(!s) {
        functionStruct *newp = new functionStruct;
        functionStruct old = function_list.at(0);
        newp->function_string.append(old.function_string);
        newp->start = old.start;
        newp->function_doc = "somedoc";
        function_list.replace(0,*newp);
        s = 1;
    }
    qDebug() << "pd0 contents " << function_list.at(0).function_doc

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't show what happens between those clicks. What happens if you call foo() second time immediately after first call?

Comment: nothing else is happning between 2 clicks. i am calling foo second time imidiately. Also other members of struct function struct are not changed,only function_doc changes.

Comment: Still, could you change `foo();` to `foo();foo();` and see what happens with single click?

Comment: it is printing expected results. "pd0 contents somedoc" twice

Comment: So something _is_ happening between the clicks. These kind of problems are solvable by using the debugger. At some point, either the vector itself or the content of the vector is changed. With debugger you can find out where it happens.

Comment: @spiritwolfform ya i will free that

Comment: Don't free it, delete it. You should show more code. At least the function where `foo()` is called. And the code where function_list is defined. Also, is the `foo()` really a global function or is it a member function of some class?

Comment: Ok i got it. foo and vector are parts of a class which is in another vector. and i wasnt replacing in the parent vector. Thanks !!